# How to use a PIP mode in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tap the video player to drop in to Picture-in-Picture mode. Tapping on the PiP view will present controls which can be used to pause, show info, return to full screen, or exit the application.

Comment: Have you find any sample for this?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms by default only contains Views that work on all platforms. For example an Entry -> EditText (android), UITextField (iOS), TextBox (UWP).

The Picture-in-picture ability is something that's only available on Android, which means Xamarin.Forms did not implement this.

The only way i could think of doing this is by exporting custom renderers that set the native control for a home-made xamarin.forums-view. I think you can find a good example here: http://blog.infernored.com/going-native-using-android-views-in-xamarin-forms, though i haven't tried it myself.

You'd basically use the SetNativeControl command in the OnElementChanged hook of the custom renderer to probably dom.xamarin.PictureInPicture.MovieView. Don't forget to export the renderers on the namespace.

Then you can use the XF view on your xaml-pages. I'll look in to making an sample.

Picture-in-picture sample for android-only: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-o/PictureInPicture/

Comment: have you find any sample on how to use within xamarin.forms?

Comment: Sadly not. Haven't had time yet to dive into it.